# Angular NodeJS FileUpload using client/server paradigm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, file-upload, couchbase

I am a developer on an application rewrite to Angular, NodeJS, Expressjs, and Couchbase.  One of my tasks to upload to the webserver various flat files.

Before people say to see a particular question, particular link in git or npm or jsfiddle etc, I have reviewed all these sites and have not found an example that fits the designed development style.  The environment consists of the following:
    Controller talks to presentation layer
    Controller talks to client side service
    Client Side services talks to the server side controller.

I have tried to use from jejenny/zg9re link in jsfiddle.net but ran into an issue.  It appears her example is set up for client side processing.  The $http.post occurs on the client.

My issue occurs when I attempt to post the file to the webserver, my code performs as follows:

```
Controller passes the request to client side service
Client side service passes the request to the server side controller
But the client side service is not adding the file to webserver
    I cannot figure out what is the code on the server side controller
```

I hoping to find either:

```
Explanation on how to split code in jsfiddle.net/jejenny/zg9re into client server side request to server side controller.
OR
A web example that perform the code using the client side service passing file to the server side controller to upload to the webserbver
```

TIA

Comment: Without your code this is pretty pointless.

Comment: code sample used http://jsfiddle.net/jejenny/zg9re

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the uploader part of the code, but the binding is not working with the directive, so the file name never reaches that portion. There are other directives out there that don't have this issue, but you can also just add an id to your file input and then use: `file = document.getElementById("your id").value` in your controller to get the file name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have the directive working but the problem i have is the code associated to the post is embbeded as client side processing.  I need to extract the code out of client side and move to a server api call.

Comment: The directive is not working in the jsfiddle. Not exactly sure what you mean, you have to do a post to send the data to the server. What is the server code written in?

Comment: the paradigm used is as follows:  X.html talks to x.controller.js.  x.contoller.js talks to x.service.js (all 3 reside on the client side)  x.service talks to x.controller.js (server API).  All code is javascript.